# Reloading three collectionview in a viewcontroller is slow

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

In my Application there are three collectionview in a viewcontroller. Collectionview is slow on reloading collectionview data.

Eventhrough i have reloaded collection in main queue. Can anyone please help on this?

```
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [topProductCollectionView reloadData];
                    [recentProductCollectionView reloadData];
                    [specialOfferCollectionView reloadData];
                });

    Below code for collectionview cell:

        - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

            switch (collectionView.tag)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TopProductCell";
                    TopProductCell *topCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Loading image in background Queue
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
                        NSString *imageurl = [[topProducts valueForKey:@"image"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
                         NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]];

                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           topCell.topProductImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        });
                    });


                    topCell.topProductName.text = [[topProducts valueForKey:@"product_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

                    topCell.topProductPrice.text = [[topProducts valueForKey:@"product_finalprice"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

                    return topCell;
                }
                    break;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "slow"? And also please provide us with some code, like how the cells are constructed and if there's a custom collection view layout.

Comment: It takes time to bind label and image's in custom collection view cells.            NSString *imageurl = [[topProducts valueForKey:@"image"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]];
            topCell.topProductImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            topCell.topProductName.text = [[topProducts valueForKey:@"product_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Your  mistake  :- NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]]; Do it on background thread and your collectionview will work smoothely

Comment: Ya. I tried in background queue but still this problem exits. Below code i have tried.            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
                NSString *imageurl = [[latestProducts valueForKey:@"image"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]];
                
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    recentCell.recentProductImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                });
            });

Comment: @Lokesh Don't put code in comments. Update your question with relevant details.

Comment: ok.. I tried in background queue but still this problem exits. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Please put your code in the question. Also, with this approach you'll have problems with cell reuse.

Comment: This is the correct approach of loading images in collection view?